# ELB Health check passes. Scaling Group Shows unhealthy. With scaling group set to the ELB check

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, healthcheck

Having an issue where our ELB health checks are showing up as healthy on the ELB page. but checking on the Scaling group instances page its showing as unhealthy. 
causing the autoscaler to kill it without any need.

Despite the Box

a) being fine. Its up services on it are responding. 
b) passing the ELB health check (ping port 8080/tcp)

Box is under 0 load. No idea what is causing it.

How can ELB pass. yet the Scaling group check fail. Just to confirm. Scaling group Health check is set to use that of ELB.

Comment: What is your `HealthCheckGracePeriod` set to?

Answer (score 1):

Is the ASG set to use the ELB as its healthcheck or EC2? The EC2 healthcheck is very basic -- pretty much the only way for you to cause it to fail is to shutdown the instance or disable networking entirely. Is there any process that restarts your nodes?